# Error in LISP - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: invalid form (40)

Tags: if-statement, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am working on a Lisp program that contains code to read in the dimensions of boxes and then sort them from shortest to longest lengths (and set each of these new lengths as new variables).

When I attempt to load my file into the interpreter, I get the following error:

```
 - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: invalid form (40)
```

Assuming this error is stemming from line 40 of my code, here are lines 34-45:

```
(defun get-box ()
    (let ((d1) (d2) (d3))
        (setf d1 (read))
        (setf d2 (read))
        (setf d3 (read))
        (list d1 d2 d3))
        (if (= -1 d1)
            (exit)
            (setf new-d1 (first (sort (d1 d2 d3)) #'<))
            (setf new-d2 (second (sort (d1 d2 d3)) #'<))
            (setf new-d3 (third (sort (d1 d2 d3)) #'<))
            (next-part-of-program (new-d1, new-d2, new-d3)))
```

Is there anything inherently wrong syntactically or semantically with my `if` statement in this code snippet? What does the `EXPAND-FORM` error come from/mean in Lisp?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This `(40)` has nothing to do with line numbers. It means that you either have a literal 40 in your code in an inappropriate place or a variable which you evaluate with your commas evaluates to 40.

Comment: Wow, that definitely changes things. Thanks; I'll investigate towards the beginning of my program because I do set some variables to the value 40.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing this out. I found out my error came from not initializing the variable I set to 40. Thanks again!!

Comment: This has the same problem (if not others) that the code in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20170661/1281433) did, `(sort (d1 d2 d3))` will be an error, since `d1` probably isn't a function, and `(new-d1, new-d2, new-d3)` has a bunch of commas (commata?) that don't belong.

Comment: `if` has a maximum of three arguments, a condition, a then-part, and an (optional) else-part.  Your `if` has a whole bunch.  Also note that you can combine `(setf w x) (setf y z)` into `(setf w x y z)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see a message mentioning symbols in the `"SYS"` package (also known as `"SI"` and `"SYSTEM"`  in different implementations), especially when the symbols are internal (prefixed with two colons), and, moreover, their names contain non-alphanumeric characters (e.g., `%` or `$`), chances are this message is implementation-specific, and you will help us help you by mentioning which implementation you are using.

That said, I think you are using `CLISP`, in which case this `40` does *not* name a line in your file.

You either have a literal `40` in an inappropriate place in your file, or you have a variable with the value of `40` which you evaluate during macroexpansion with a misplaced comma.

Answer (score 3):

An `if` can have only a *single* expression for the consequent, and a single for the alternative (the "else" part). If you need to write more than one expression, pack them inside `progn`. I believe this is what you intended:

```
(if (= d1 -1) ; condition. It's bad style to write Yoda conditions!
    (exit) ; consequent
    (progn ; alternative
     …))
```

Also, be aware that there seems to be a misplaced parentheses at the end of this line:

```
(list d1 d2 d3))
```

… And anyway, the above line is doing nothing, you can simply delete it. Also this part is wrong:

```
(sort (d1 d2 d3)) #'<)
```

It should be:

```
(sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<)
```

And in here, the commas are wrong:

```
(new-d1, new-d2, new-d3)
```

Also, in this line the variables should have an initial value, and you should also declare `new-d1`, `new-d2` and `new-d3`

```
(let ((d1) (d2) (d3))
```

With all the fixes in place, this is how the code should look:

```
(defun get-box ()
  (let ((d1 0) (d2 0) (d3 0) (new-d1 0) (new-d2 0) (new-d3 0))
    (setf d1 (read))
    (setf d2 (read))
    (setf d3 (read))
    (if (= d1 -1)
        (exit)
        (progn
          (setf new-d1 (first  (sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<)))
          (setf new-d2 (second (sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<)))
          (setf new-d3 (third  (sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<)))
          (next-part-of-program new-d1 new-d2 new-d3)))))
```

Comment: @user1462294 is this right? I'm not sure if the `(exit)` part is supposed to be executed only if `(= -1 d1)` or always. You can see why your code was wrong, it's impossible to tell where the consequent starts and where the alternative starts!

Comment: Thanks for your input! You are right the `exit` is only supposed to happen if `d1=-1`... However, I tried using `progn` and I got the same `EXPAND-FORM` error on line 40. Is there anything else that the EXPAND-FORM error might indicate in this `if` statement?

Comment: @user1462294 also, I believe there's a wrong closing parentheses at the end of this line: `(list d1 d2 d3))`. Delete it, and make sure to correctly close the other parentheses

Comment: @user1462294 and there's _yet another_ error in the part where you're sorting, that's not how you build a list!. See my updated code

Comment: @user1462294 I keep finding syntax errors, hopefully I caught them all - I guess you're just learning Lisp. See my last update.

Comment: You can tell I'm just learning Lisp? :) Jokes aside, I really appreciate your help. However, I put your last edit's code exactly as-is and still got the same error (still on line 40, which is no longer the starting if statement)... Any other ideas? Thanks again...

Comment: And in my code, where's line 40 now? try recompiling, it might be just that

Comment: @user1462294 good grief, syntax errors keep appearing :( this time I checked with my compiler, see my re-updated answer again. I hope this one is worth an accept ;)

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this syntax! I very much appreciate it!